# Receiving HTTP request params in Lift

Tags: http, scala, post, lift

I'm a Lift newbie and I can't digest it's HTTP request/response cycle yet. Handling REST is thoroughly explained in Lift docs but what I'm looking for is much simpler: how do I access HTTP request body/params in my web service (in Scala code of course) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Lift 2.0, then you can use [`S.getRequestHeader()`](http://main.scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.0/framework/scaladocs/net/liftweb/http/S$object.html).

Answer (score 0):

To get HTTP param with given name, you can use method [S.param(parameter_name)](http://liftweb.net/api/25/api/net/liftweb/http/S$.html).